# Using Silex FormServiceProvider without twig

Tags: php, forms, silex

How can I render a form built with Silex `FormServiceProvider` without using twig?

I tried both `$form` and `$form->createView()`, I also looked at the API documentation for both Form and FormView and it is not abvious to me how can I do that.

Here is my code:

```
$app->get('/form', function (Request $request) use ($app) {
    // some default data for when the form is displayed the first time
    $data = array(
        'name' => 'Your name',
        'email' => 'Your email',
    );

    $form = $app['form.factory']->createBuilder(FormType::class, $data)
       ->add('name')
       ->add('email')
       ->add('billing_plan', ChoiceType::class, array(
           'choices' => array(
               1 => 'free', 
               2 => 'small_business', 
               3 => 'corporate'
            ),
            'expanded' => true,
       ))
       ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    // I want return the form here
    return 'ok';
});
```

Comment: In order to render a form, you need an instance of a [FormRenderer](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.0/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormRenderer.php) class which in turn uses a [FormRendererEngine](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.0/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormRendererEngineInterface.php). There is an [AbstractFormRendererEngine](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.0/src/Symfony/Component/Form/AbstractRendererEngine.php) from which you can try to work but I higly recommend you to use Twig, you'll have everything you need out of the box

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this : http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/book/forms.html#rendering-the-form

```
$formView = $form->createView();
$html = $formView->start($form) .
$formView->widget($form) .
$formView->end($form);
```

Truth be told, I didn't have time to check this, but it might help.